# How can I change the color of the WPF DataGrid sort direction triangle?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

In my DataGrid, I've styled the column headers to have a background color which seems to match the sort direction triangle, effectively making the triangle invisible. In order to let the user see the sort direction triangle, I'd like to change its color. How can I do that?

I've studied Microsoft's online [DataGrid style and template documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates), but I can't find any reference to the sort direction triangle.

Comment: You take the default datagrid template and overwrite it

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how did you figure that out? Specifically, how do you know it is necessary to overwrite the DataGrid template, rather than re-styling the default template?

Comment: Im not sure i expressed myself that well. There is no "PART_SortIcon" that is offered as a dependencyproperty by the datagrid for you to edit. So you copy paste the default template of the datagrid, find that sort triangle and edit it as you like. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense; thank you. Unfortunately, the part I'm struggling with is "find that sort triangle". I studied the XAML on the DataGrid documentation page, but I see no sort triangle there.

Comment: here is an old post with an example how its done, copy-paste go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4487962/6449190. im not sure why i cant find the sorticon on the msdn pages :/

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Ordinarily, we'd be able to re-style something like this, but the sort icon is an exception. The sort icon is defined in an Aero theme, and Aero themes can't be re-styled (?), so it is necessary to re-template the part of the DataGrid that uses the Aero theme, and we can style that template however we'd like. Thanks for helping me to figure this out.

Comment: yes, if you take the .net reflector and look into presentationframework.aero you will find a template for datagrid, specifically DataGridColumnHeader, which has a DataGridHeaderBorder inside it, which is a special border which displays that sorticon thingy by default, UNLESS you define a background manually, in which case no sorticon comes from it... if you take the code from the link i gave you and remove the background setter in DataGridColumnHeader, you will see that you now have 2 sorticons, one default, and one that you see in your xaml. good luck

Comment: here is how the triangle is drawn (OnRender method) https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework.Classic/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/DataGridHeaderBorder.cs,df4801141097df54