# WPF MVVM - Trigger datagrid sort direction's arrow programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

By default when my DataGrid is load, my data will be sort by ProductName asc. However, the gridview's ProductName header will not show the arrow up icon. Is that anyway for me to trigger the icon programmatically?

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridProduct" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductResult}" 
          Style="{StaticResource defaultDataGridStyle}" 
          CellStyle="{StaticResource defaultCellStyle}"
          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource defaultCellHeaderStyle}"> 
  <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Price" Binding="{Binding ProducPrice}"/> 
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="defaultCellHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="defaultCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
</Style>
```

MVVM:

```
public List<Product> ProductResult
{
    get
    {
        _productResult = _productResult.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        return _productResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting, Selection Tracking and Filtering (if you do any on the GUI side) in MVVM is usually done via a CollectionView. If you do not hand the controls one, they will create one automagically. You propably need to take control of it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
SortDirection="Ascending"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to synchronize the effective sort to the visual style on column, this should help :

```
( (INotifyCollectionChanged)Items.SortDescriptions ).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( OnItemsSortDescriptionsChanged );


private void OnItemsSortDescriptionsChanged( object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    //Synchronize effective sorting in the grid and Visual style on columns
    if ( Items != null )
    {
        foreach ( DataGridColumn column in Columns )
        {
            column.SortDirection = null;

            foreach ( SortDescription sd in Items.SortDescriptions )
            {
                if ( column.SortMemberPath == sd.PropertyName )
                {
                    column.SortDirection = sd.Direction;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```